# Nested QHash Not Saving

Tags: qt, qt5, qhash

I have a function `read` (that takes and returns `void`), which stores data from a file into a `QHash<QString,QHash<QString,QString> >` -- for clarity, let's call any QHash fitting this template `hash`. My aim was to make a "master" list of all the `hash`es that exist, which would be a `QHash<QHash<QString,QHash<QString,QString> > >` -- let's call this `masterHash`. Within `read`, everything is fine: `masterHash["hash1"]` and `hash1` are identical.

I have another function `write` (that takes a QString of the form`"hash1"` and returns `void`), which stores data from `masterHash["hash1"]` to a file. Now, this was my aim in creating `masterHash` in the first place -- to access `hash1` from `"hash1"`. Within `write`, `hash1` still contains the things that were stored in `read`, but `masterHash["hash1"]` is now empty (though `masterHash` still contains the key `"hash1"`).

What am I doing wrong or missing? There is no QHash dereferencing anywhere. (Originally, I didn't even store to `hash1`, but I was trying to figure out why `masterHash["hash1"]` wasn't saving.)

Alternately, is there a better way to achieve the same goal (pointing to a hash using a string of its name)?

Comment: `QHash<QHash<QString,QHash<QString,QString> > >` is missing the key (QString?). Add some minimal code, it's hard to follow and hard to judge what's going on without code. Note that if you insert hash1 into masterhash and then modify hash1, masterhash will be unaffected, as the value inserted is always a copy, not a reference to the original value.

Comment: I agree with Frank about it. This is a typical example when code is worth of many words. It is a bit weird to describe code with only text on this low-level.